# How to add custom dynamic class to the view row in field handler?

Tags: views

I'm implementing custom [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) field handler and need to add entity_id-based class to the row. When the field is enabled in view it should add class to the whole row.

Comment: Refer [this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/how-do-i-add-extra-classes-to-a-date-field-at-views)

Comment: Thanks, Abin, but it doesn't suit my needs. I need completely standalone solution within my handler code.

Comment: My first thought is to use a `template_preprocess_field` hook on this. Otherwise, a Views post-render?